# Apache Tiles with Gradle not working in spring boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, gradle

I have been trying to create the Sample application having Apache Tiles with Gradle in spring boot. Now I am getting below error at runtime

```
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/view/layout/main.jsp]
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@5f84d53b] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/view/layout/main.jsp] are [/**]
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/view/layout/main.jsp] are {}
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/WEB-INF/view/layout/main.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@51abf713]]] and 1 interceptor
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@5c48030d]
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@47949c09]
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/view/layout/main.jsp] is: -1
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Applying "invalid path" checks to path: WEB-INF/view/layout/main.jsp
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Path contains "WEB-INF" or "META-INF".
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Ignoring invalid resource path [WEB-INF/view/layout/main.jsp]
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@6a0b5a41
2017-08-29 22:58:08 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

It has been working fine if I replace the gradle project with maven. I have created both gradle & maven build scripts. You may find sample project at [this](https://github.com/abhi3232/IDP) location. I think issue is with the gradle's provided scope.

**build.gradle file, Not working somehow**

```
// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'


configurations {
    provided
}



// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
}   

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version: '3.0.7'
    provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version: '3.0.7'
    provided 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.2.RELEASE'
    provided 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'



}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    //test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    //test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}

eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += [configurations.provided]
```

**Working pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-web-mvc</name>
    <description>
        Configure spring boot starter project for Web MVC as a WAR file, still self executing.
    </description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.mvmlabs.springboot.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to allow configuration as a web MVC, built as a WAR file (still 
            executable) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Apache Tiles into the mix -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <groupId>idp</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.proginators.idp</artifactId>
</project>
```

***Any help or suggesting is highly appreciated.***

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working with gradle project.

Just add the following dependency

providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'

2017-11-29 11:44:08.302  INFO 5760 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-11-29 11:44:08.302  INFO 5760 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-11-29 11:44:08.323  INFO 5760 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms
2017-11-29 11:47:52.678  WARN 5760 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/basic.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'